# What rules or guidelines should I follow before doing Udgeeth?

Tags: guru, meditation, om, pranayama

There used to be some recommended rules and guidelines to follow before doing any [Pranayama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pranayama) and [meditation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditation).

**Udgeeth** involves chanting of AUM (OM) with every exhalation.

We do **Udgeeth** in a sequence of Pranayam like **Bhastrika, Kapalbhati, Anulom Vilom, Bhramari** and then **Udgeeth**. So I don't know whether I should call **Udgeeth** a Pranayama or Meditation.

Can I do **Udgeeth** any time? What are associated guidelines or rules for doing **Udgeeth**? Like in the case of other meditation people recommended for empty stomach and morning time and we should do it under guidance of some Guru. How seriously such guidelines should I take in case of **Udgeeth**?

In short, are there any guidelines to follow before doing **Udgeeth** or I can do anytime whenever I am feeling like to do?

Comment: You can  simply follow the teachings of Baba Ramdev regarding these pranayamas.